# D3 JS Whats the meaning of the F passed to the anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, anonymous-function

I am trying to learn D3 and i am having a hard time to understand the anonymous functions.

In the following example, there is at the bottom function(f) and it returns returns the variable "interpolate" with the parameter f (which i think is itself akward, since "interpolate" is not a function, but a variable).

But what is the meaning of F? I do not see how or where it is used in the function of "interpolate". If i delete F and just pass (), my animation breaks.

Thanks! :)

```
svg.append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', line(lineData))
        .transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .attrTween('d', pathTween);

    function pathTween() {
        var interpolate = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0,1])
                .range(d3.range(0, 7));
        return function(f) {
            return line(lineData.slice(0, interpolate(f)));
        };
    }
```

Comment: Your `pathTween()` creates a function which is sent to d3. At some point d3 then decides to call your function and pass it one parameter - `f`.

Comment: Not strictly related to D3, but Js in general, you might want to take a look at [what a closure is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and how it works. Make sure you understand what happens when a function returns another function that accepts a parameter., like in this case.

Comment: @Nobita It is specific to `D3`, as it all boils down to the fact that the `d3.scale.quantile` returns a function, for which `f` will be between 0 and 1 for the duration of the animation. That `interpolate` variable's then gonna convert numbers to an appropriate range.

Comment: @Ian "Not strictly related to D3" was referring to the fact that in case the OP does not know what happens in a closure - which we have here - it could be a good (actually it is a an essential)  pre-requisite to understand the d3 implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
....
.attrTween('d', pathTween);

function pathTween() {
    var interpolate = d3.scale.quantile()
            .domain([0,1])
            .range(d3.range(0, 7));
    return function(f) {
        return line(lineData.slice(0, interpolate(f)));
    };
}
```

1. We are passing the closure function `pathTween` to `attrTween`.  Under the hood `d3` will invoke `pathTween` for every element in your selection (in your case it's just one `path`).
2. `d3` is expecting the function passed to `attrTween` to return a function.  This is the anonymous function which takes parameter `f` (most `d3` examples will use variable `t`, more on that in a second).
3. The `pathTween` function is a closure because it creates the inner **variable** `interpolate` and closes it so that it's available in the inner returned function.  You stated `it returns the variable "interpolate" with the parameter f (which i think is itself awkward, since "interpolate" is not a function but a variable)`. This is not true; first, we don't return `interpolate` at all (but it is available in the closure ) and second, it is a **function that is being stored in a variable**.  Storing functions in variables is very common in JavaScript (and a lot of other programming languages too).
4. Now that `d3` has the inner anon function, it's going to call it for every tick of the animation (usually every 16ms).  When it calls it, its going to pass in `f`.  What's `f`?  It's a timer (why it's usually called `t`).  It'll contain a value from 0 to 1 that indicates where it is in the transition (0 is start, 1 in end).  This variable is then passed to the *function* `interpolate`, which happens to be expecting a value between 0 and 1 (see `domain[0,1]`).

Check this out:

```js
var interpolate = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0,1])
                .range(d3.range(0, 7));
                
console.log(typeof(interpolate));

console.log(interpolate(0));
console.log(interpolate(0.25));
console.log(interpolate(0.5));
console.log(interpolate(1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, functions can be passed around in a variable! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

```
var interpolate = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0,1])
                .range(d3.range(0, 7));
```

in this line, D3 creates a new function for you and it is then assigned to the  variable `interpolate` ready to be executed at a later time

```
return function(f) {
            return line(lineData.slice(0, interpolate(f)));
        };
```

This then returns a function that can be called by D3. When D3 calls this function it passes in a value for f which your interpolate function can use as input. Removing f would mean the value `undefined` is passed to the function instead.

Comment: You don't actually explain what the parameter `f` is though, which I'm assuming what the question is asking.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I used D3. Thought it was still worthwhile as OP seemed like they were most confused about passing functions around. Accepted answer is much better than mine _b